# _helper->redirector, imagepaths lost

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using the following helper to redirect to the index action of the bibliothek controller.

```
$urlOptions = array('controller'=>'bibliothek', 'action'=>'index');     
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute($urlOptions);
```

It works, but: My images in the form are lost, I use some icons for example:

```
<img src="Images/Icons/plus.jpg" ...
```

So how does it work with the relative paths? How can I solve it?

Comment: It's not really clear.. You forgot in your array the module. Then about "My Images at the form are lost", you have **a form** which you have submitted and you lost data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and added the baseurl to my layout.phtml baseUrl().'/' ; ?>" /> –